# Reference Python code in previous cell [Jupyter Notebook]

Tags: import, cell, jupyter

I have a script I want to summarize in Jupyter Notebook by putting some markdown cells in between cells of the code. Is is possible to set up some variables and functions in one cell, add cell(s) after, then reference the earlier variables or functions in a later cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Any (top level) variable or function that is defined in one cell can be used in subsequent cells.

Comment: Oh wow do I feel silly. I tested this  by using an import method from a previous cell and got an error. Easy problem to solve at least.